# Pop-up form that creates record that links 1:1 to main form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a pop-up form that opens using a button on the main form in a MS Access database. The pop-up form creates a new record (in a separate table) that needs to link to the current record in the main form. How do I set this up properly?

The two forms (frmMain, frmWB) are based on 2 separate tables (tblMain and tblWB). The records have a 1:1 relationship (each main record can only have one WB1 record).

The main form (frmMain) has the primary key [ID]

The pop-up from (frmWB) has the primary key [WBID] (autonumber) and [MainID] (number).

Data entry personnel will enter the main info first (this will have to be required to avoid orphans), then click a button that saves the main record and opens the pop-up form to add the detailed info. When done, they click the close button which saves the pop-up record, closes the pop-up, and returns to the main form (which stayed open in behind). Navigation has been disabled in the pop-up and it is set to cycle the current record.

I have tried linking using the primary IDs for the two tables, but that doesn't seem to reliably link the correct ID numbers when adding a new record in the pop-up. I tried using subforms, but had problems if the navigation or 'new record' buttons on the main form were accidentally hit when entering data in the subform - that created records in tblWB that had the wrong ID numbers.

Comment: The usual way is to set the foreign key in the `BeforeInsert` event of the popup form. Have you tried that? This assumes that the popup is a bound form.

Comment: Hi Andre, what code would I use to set the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

If frmWB is opened modal, so that the current record of frmMain can't be changed while the popup is open, you would have this in the [`BeforeInsert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835397.aspx) event procedure of frmWB:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me!MainID = Forms!frmMain!ID
End Sub
```

This automatically assigns the tblMain ID to the newly created tblWB record.

`MainID` should be an invisible textbox on frmWB, bound to the table field `MainID`. While debugging you can make it visible, but it should be locked.

If frmWB isn't modal, I would use [`OpenArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836583.aspx) to pass the ID from frmMain to frmWB. And then use that in `Form_BeforeInsert` instead of `Forms!frmMain!ID`

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to Andre's comment, the usual way is to create a relationship between the two tables, enforce referential integrity and use cascading updates.

While [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304466) is specific to Office 2003, the concept is the same for all versions of Access.  If you do this, the popup will automatically create a new record linked to the main form's record.

Comment: He's inserting records, not updating primary keys. How will the relationship automatically set the foreign key between independent forms?

Comment: He's adding a new record in one table based on a record in another.  That's precisely what cascading updates do.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Cascading updates propagate **changes** in Primary Keys to related tables. -- From the article you linked: "If you click to select the Cascade Update Related Fields check box when you define a relationship, any time that you *change the primary key* of a record in the primary table, Microsoft Access automatically updates the primary key to the new value in all related records."

Comment: Microsoft apparently left out some info, including the fact that when you enforce referential integrity between two tables with a one-to-one join, the second table creates a new record for the same primary key that gets created in the first table.

Comment: This is perhaps not the right place to discuss this (sorry Amarok!), but do you have a reference for that? It sounds interesting, but I created a simple example in Access 2010: http://i.imgur.com/Y2UUu3B.png -- and creating a record in `tMaster` didn't create a record in `tChild`. I would have been surprised if it had - as I see it, 1:1 relationships are in fact "1 : (0..1)" just as 1:n are "1 : (0..n)".